# Asm: Trying to compare two integers - I'm getting the WRONG answer

Tags: ubuntu, assembly

I'm quite new to this - `Ubuntu` + `as`.

I'm trying to do a simple comparison between two integers and show a message. Here's my code:

```
.data
    MsgA:   .ascii "A is higher\n"
    MsgB:   .ascii "B is higher\n"
.text

.global _start

_start:

    movl $25, %eax
    movl $15, %ebx
    cmp %eax, %ebx      #Compare the two (eax - ebx)
    jg AHire        #If result is bigger, A Hire

    #say that B is hire 
    movl $4, %eax
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl $MsgB, %ecx    #Otherwise B Hire
    movl $10, %edx
    int $0x80

    jmp EndProg

#say that A is hire
AHire:  
    movl $4, %eax
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl $MsgA, %ecx
    movl $10, %edx
    int $0x80

EndProg:
    movl $1, %eax
    movl $0, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

While I hope I'm on the right track, I am kind of puzzled as to why the output is "B is hire". Shouldn't the comparison return a positive value since according to the docs, **cmp** does a subtraction of the 2nd value from the 1st?

Thanks for any support on this!

Comment: Just out of interest, are you _sure_ you're using `nasm`? I was of the understanding it used Intel syntax rather than AT&T.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu and I'm assembling my code using **as** from the terminal then linking with **ld**. Does that confirm that it's nasm? I've seen some docs using gcc to link. Not too sure :/

Comment: No, it's almost certainly using `gas`, the GNU assembler. I think I'll just change the tag to assembly until you're certain which one you're using.

Comment: How would I know exactly if I'm using NASM? I mean all the instructions I've picked up this far have been based on the NASM docs here: https://cs.fit.edu/~mmahoney/cse3101/nasmdocb.html

Comment: If you're using `nasm`, you'll almost certainly be typing `nasm` on the command line rather than `as` :-) In addition, it will baulk at your AT&T notation input files. The information you're looking at is still useful since the encoding of instructions doesn't change based on the input format. However, if you want to know how to write the equivalent AT&T source code, be aware of the differences: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've fallen afoul of the `AT&T/Intel` notation differences. In *Intel* notation, the source comes last, such as with loading `eax` with the immediate value `1`:

```
mov eax, 1
```

In *AT&T* notation, that would be written as:

```
movl $1, %eax
```

Hence your instruction:

```
cmp %eax, %ebx
```

gives you the result of performing `ebx - eax`, not your erroneous assumption of `eax - ebx`. It's equivalent to the Intel notation of:

```
cmp ebx, eax
```

---

And, though it's irrelevant to your problem at hand, the correct word here is `higher` (more high than) rather than `hire` (pay someone for the use of something).

*And* you can possibly make your code more maintainable if you use calculation to get the string lengths. That way, if you change the strings to, for example, `"A is higher\n"`, you won't need to track down and change the hard-coded length of ten as well. First change your data to:

```
.data
    MsgA:   .ascii "A is hire\n"
    MsgB:   .ascii "B is hire\n"
    MsgC:
```

Then change the code that loads up the length to one of:

```
    movl MsgB-MsgA, %edx  ; for printing MsgA
    movl MsgC-MsgB, %edx  ; for printing MsgB
```

That calculates the length using actual labels so that it will auto-magically adjust to a different string size.

Comment: I stand corrected, hands down. I can't believe I made this mistake in English. Must've been exhausted... Thanks!

Comment: I learnt about the difference as you've mentioned. I assumed the cmp worked like it said from the docs that mentioned **"CMP performs a `mental' subtraction of its second operand from its first operand"** and that's why I used eax - ebx

Comment: @itsols, it _does_ subtract the second operand from the first, it's just that, in AT&T syntax, the second operand comes first :-) The nasm program uses Intel syntax so you should not rely on its doco if you're using an AT&T syntax assembler like `gas`. The major differences are shown at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax (so you can adjust) but you're probably better off using doco specifically targeted to the assembler you're using.