# How do I interpret this instruction?

Tags: assembly, nasm, semantics

Trying to understand how **cmp** works with **NASM**, On [this page](https://cs.fit.edu/~mmahoney/cse3101/nasmdocb.html) I found the following:

```
CMP r/m32,reg32               ; o32 39 /r            [386]
```

There are more like this. However, I cannot understand what this line means.

I presume [386] refers to the processor/architecture. Can someone please explain the meaning of the ASM statement?

Comment: I recommend you use the official instruction set reference from intel, and don't forget to read section _3.1 Interpreting the instruction reference pages_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r/m32` and `reg32` are operand specifications. The first means a 32-bit register or memory operand, the second is a 32-bit register. Section `B.1 Key to operand specifications` of that page you link to explains this:

> Registers: reg8 denotes an 8-bit general purpose register, reg16 denotes a 16-bit general purpose register, and **reg32 a 32-bit one.** fpureg denotes one of the eight FPU stack registers, mmxreg denotes one of the eight 64-bit MMX registers, and segreg denotes a segment register. In addition, some registers (such as AL, DX or ECX) may be specified explicitly.
>
> Memory references: **mem denotes a generic memory reference; mem8, mem16, mem32, mem64 and mem80 are used when the operand needs to be a specific size.** Again, a specifier is needed in some cases: DEC [address] is ambiguous and will be rejected by NASM. You must specify DEC BYTE [address], DEC WORD [address] or DEC DWORD [address] instead.
>
> Register or memory choices: many instructions can accept either a register or a memory reference as an operand. **r/m8 is a shorthand for reg8/mem8; similarly r/m16 and r/m32.** r/m64 is MMX-related, and is a shorthand for mmxreg/mem64.

Similarly, section `B.2 Key to opcode descriptions` shows how the opcode/operands are encoded:

> **The codes o16 and o32 indicate that the given form of the instruction should be assembled with operand size 16 or 32 bits.** In other words, o16 indicates a 66 prefix in BITS 32 state, but generates no code in BITS 16 state; and o32 indicates a 66 prefix in BITS 16 state but generates nothing in BITS 32.

That explains the `o32`.

> **A hex number,** such as 3F, indicates a fixed byte containing that number.

That covers the `39`, a fixed opcode.

> The code /r ... indicates that one of the operands is a memory address or r/m, and another is a register, and that an effective address should be generated with the spare (register) field in the ModR/M byte being equal to the `register value' of the register operand.

And that details how the other operands are stored, though it's not a simple process since there's usually some bit fiddling required. I'd suggest following the links given in that section to the sections detailing how effective addresses and registers are encoded.

The `[386]` is the level at which the opcode/operand set was introduced.

---

If you *really* want to understand the encoding, assemble a few different variations of the `cmp` statement, and have a look at the machine code they generate. Then try to disassemble them back into source code using sections `B.1`, `B.2`, `B.2.1` and `B.2.5`.

That will hopefully greatly speed your understanding of how it works.

Comment: Thank you. But why does the comment have some weird numbers - **o32 39 /r** ?

Comment: @itsols you should at least read the page you have linked ... all of this is explained starting with section _B1_ as paxdiablo said. `o32` means 32 bit operand, `39` is the opcode, `/r` is an encoding modifier.

Comment: @Jester Thank you! Trust me, I am reading through them... So many cros-references are taking me in circles. I missed out this section B1. Sorry about that.

Comment: @itsols, I've updated the answer with some more quotes from the relevant pages but I found it's best to punch an instruction into an assembler and see what comes out (machine code), then use that and the sections detailing encoding of effective addresses and registers to try turn it back into assembler code. Once you've done that for a few different variations, you'll understand the encoding quite a bit more. In fact, I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: @paxdiablo I *AM* testing them out. In fact this question is a result of my program not giving the expected result. Excuse me for my ignorance but I tried using the **cmp** instruction for a comparison and got a strange result. Perhaps I' doing it wrong. Here's my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22440613/nasm-trying-to-compare-two-integers-im-getting-the-wrong-answer

Comment: @paxdiablo I think you meant section A.1 and not B.1 :)

Comment: @itsols, no, the link you gave is to appendix B. The sections as given are correct.

Comment: oh no! I've been having two identical pages with different URLs and on one it's Appendix A and on the other it's B. Thanks! FYI, here's the other link: http://home.myfairpoint.net/fbkotler/nasmdocc.html

Comment: @itsols, I'd steer clear of that one (in the comment), it contains "This is derived from the old, obsolete, and potentially buggy instruction set reference from the old Nasm Manual. The Nasm development team explicitly disclaims any responsibility for errors and omissions in this document!".

Comment: My apologies. Dr. Mahoney's version is even older - check out "pushf" in his version! :) Confirm that Intel is your "go to" documentation... but I like the Nasm version. No use for (G)as, either of 'em.

Comment: @Frank, you may be right, the myfairpoint one mention x86-64 and the other only mentions 80x86. Best bet is to actually download the Intel docs themselves and use `nasm` or another assembler that supports Intel format. I seem to recall that gas _does_ support both formats but, if you're happier with nasm, use it by all means.